# How to check for data from one file in another and remove the row with that data in second file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files:

**file1:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

**file2:**

```
ab|1|234|ks|
fg|6|567|fg|
fg|19|576|ik|
sd|3|879|jh|
```

Now i have to search the data from file1 in file2, and remove the rows containing it in column 2.

like here, the output should be :

```
fg|19|576|ik|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } !($2 in a)' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

- `-F '|'` set field separator for input
- `NR==FNR` matches the first file only (total record number equals file record number)
- `a[$0]` adds the input line as a valid index to array `a`
- `next` skips further processing of the input line, so everything after this will only be done for the second (to last) file(s)
- `!($2 in a)` condition: second field is not a valid index in array `a`, with implicit action `print`